# Serilog's CouchDB sink doesn't seem to be using LogContext

Tags: c#, logging, couchdb, serilog

I'm not sure how to use Serilog's LogContext with the CouchDB sink.

A simple example to show my current usage:

```
using (LogContext.PushProperty("Track", "hi"))
{
    this.Log.Information("test");
}
```

And what I see in CouchDB Futon:
[image: Test]

My understanding is that LogContext will add a "Track" field with the value of "hi" to all Serilog logs until it's disposed.  But, I'm not seeing that happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Not sure how to answer my own question, I found the solution with further research.)

In order to use the LogContext class like I was, the logger needs to be initialized with:
`.Enrich.FromLogContext()`

I thought I had done this, but I ...didn't.

```
this.Log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
    .WriteTo.CouchDB("http://127.0.0.1:5984/logs")
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();
```

This is explained at: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment